# facing error for statically allocated class!

Tags: iphone

what can be possible reason for error "statically allocated the instance of objective c class uitableview" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the ObjC Programming Guide;

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Or you could just fix it via

```
MyClass *foo = nil;
```

instead of;

```
MyClass foo = nil;
```

notice the * character, its important. To find out why you really need to read the docs.

Answer (score 0):

Guess it means that there is a variable that is globally scoped or class member and you declare that variable again in a lower scope.